# Automated reports with FreePBX 2.8.1.4

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

FreePBX has a 'Reports' tab that allows you to create a few reports and some of them you can export as a .csv or .pdf, but it doesn't really have any finer features than that. I would ultimately like to be able to have a report automatically e-mailed at the end of each day with call statistics, but I'm not seeing any way to do that. The oldest article I could find with google-fu on the subject was done back in 2008 with a much older version, so I'm just wondering if there is an easy-ish (we all dream, right?) to do automatic reporting with FreePBX.

**Edit**: I noticed there is a module (http://redmine.colsolgrp.net/projects/list_files/csreporting) that can be used. Albeit, there is not a lot of good information on this module that I've found thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shameless plug :) but you could try my product [SAMReports](http://samreports.com/), it works with FreePBX, as well as with other Asterisk editions .

Comment: Hey! I was looking at the software, it's pretty neat. However, do you have any automation of the reports? I've been moving through it and the reporting options seem to all be manual. No way to set up automatic e-mails or at least exports  (could write a script to e-mail out reports if I could at least export the data to a file on a schedule) or if there's a way I don't know to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that automation (of any kind) is not implemented, at the moment. You are the third person to ask for such a functionality, so I might consider implementing it into future releases. I haven't implemented it so far, for it would require the application to run in several "modes". Like a service application, maybe, connected to the Win scheduler functionality. Or maybe I would have to add another module for scheduling only. That would require some time, and I haven't had much free time lately.